# Search Engine not allowing me to see .net error page

Tags: c#

I just installed visual studio 2012 on fresh WIndows 7 Machine and I have having some trouble for some reason I do not no why when I go to debug a page it is naivagating away from the .net error message and going to the following url

https://uk.search.yahoo.com/yhs/errorhandler?hsimp=yhse-001&hspart=CND&type=A8BEEAEA654BA49E583F_s_g_e&q=http://localhost:49573/admin/users/default.aspx

There is nothing in my code to tell it to go yahoo  and iis express is running  has anyone ever encourted this before on a fresh machine

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: If you just navigate to the last part of that URL, http://localhost:49573/admin/users/default.aspx
, does it work? The browser could be doing a search with default search engine when it couldn't bring up the URL.

Comment: no it keeps going back to yahoo even though iis express is showing the site up in the right hand icon

Comment: sorry but how the hell can i be marked down on this if i find out this is jason again I swear I am going to be putting in a complaint

Comment: What's the behavior if you use another browser? Can you telnet into the 49573 port? It will also help if you use fiddler or just the f12 developer tool to see the traffic from the browser

Comment: to evreyone found out chrome was at fault ie is working fine chrome seems to be to easy hijack in installs off the web